# Parsing associative array via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following associative array and i try to send it to the server via AJAX.

Checking my console, in the network tab, it's posted but nothing is parsed.

**Array creation:**

```
   var FiltersArray = [];

    FiltersArray['category'] = this.category.val(); 
    FiltersArray['Type1'] = this.type1.val(); 
    FiltersArray['Type2'] = this.type2.val();
```

**Assoc array (console.log):**

`[category: "6", Type1: "998", Type2: "20100100"]`

**Request:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: POST,
    url: 'something.php',
    data: {
        data: FiltersArray 
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log('Server Response: ' + data);
})
```

Complete code:

```
          $(document).ready(function() {
    var filters = {
        category: $("#categoryInp"),
        type1: $("#type1Inp"),
        type2: $("#type2Inp"),
        button: $("#FilterBtn"),

        returnArray: function() {
            var FiltersArray = [];

            FiltersArray['category'] = this.category.val();
            FiltersArray['Type1'] = this.type1.val();
            FiltersArray['Type2'] = this.type2.val();

            return FiltersArray;
        },
        sendRequest: function(type, URL) {
            $.ajax({
                type: type,
                url: URL,
                data: JSON.stringify(this.returnArray()),

                beforeSend: function() {}

            }).done(function(data) {
                console.log('Server Response: ' + data);
            }).fail(function() {
                alert("An error occurred!");
            });
        }
    };

    filters.button.on('click', e => {
        console.log(filters.returnArray());
        filters.sendRequest('POST', 'Modules/Products.order.module.php');
    });

});
```

Comment: You surely mean `url: 'something.php', data: FiltersArray`

Comment: Hi @mplungjan, actually no, data expects a value, i need to send an array there.

Comment: And you really want an object: `var FiltersObj = {}` instead of an array.

Comment: Also what is `this` in this case?

Comment: Try `contentType: 'application/json', data: JSON.stringify(FiltersArray),`

Comment: added more code, at the bottom

Comment: Your code is still incomplete

Comment: As @Andy has mentioned, you might want to use a [javascript json objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp) like `var FiltersObj = {}`

Comment: @SASSY_ROG — That isn't JSON — http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/ — Do not trust W3Schools, they are awful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as an associative array in JavaScript.

- There are objects, which hold `key:value` pairs of data.
- There are arrays, which are a type of object that provides special behaviour when the `key` name is an integer.

jQuery distinguishes between arrays and other kinds of objects when you pass one in `data`.

If you pass an array it will **not** do anything with `key:value` pairs where the `key` is *not* an integer.

**Use a plain object and not an array for this.**

---

Aside: Variable names beginning with a capital letter are traditionally reserved for storing constructor functions in JavaScript. Don't use that naming convention for other kinds of data.

---

```
var filters = {};

filters['category'] = this.category.val(); 
filters['Type1'] = this.type1.val(); 
filters['Type2'] = this.type2.val();
```

---

It would be easier to just collect all the data as you create the object though:

```
var filters = {
    category: this.category.val(),
    Type1: this.type1.val(),
    Type2: this.type2.val()
};
```

---

*Aside*

> ```
> data: {
>     data: FiltersArray 
> }
> ```

This will create a (seemingly pointlessly) complex data structure that you'll need to access in PHP as `$_POST['data']['category']`.

You probably want just:

```
data: filters
```

---

*Aside*

```
data: JSON.stringify(this.returnArray()),
```

This will send JSON instead of form encoded data.

If you do that then you'll **also** need to:

- Set the `contentType` of the request to indicate that you are sending JSON
- [Explicitly parse the JSON in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37847337/19068)

So you *probably* don't want to do that.